# C# Sql Data not saving

Tags: sql, database, c#-4.0, data-loss

I have a few tables in a c# application I'm currently working on and for 4/5 of the tables everything saves perfectly fine no issues. For the 5th table everything seems good until I reload the program again (without modifying the code or working with a seperate install so that the data doesn't go away) The 4/5 tables are fine but the 5th doesn't have any records in it after it has been restarted (but it did the last time it was running). Below is some code excerpts. I have tried a few different solutions online including creating a string to run the sql commands on the database manually and creating the row directly as opposed to the below implementation which uses a generic data row.

```
//From main window
        private void newInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PosDatabaseDataSet.InvoicesRow newInvoice = posDatabaseDataSet1.Invoices.NewInvoicesRow();
            Invoices iForm = new Invoices(newInvoice, posDatabaseDataSet1, true);
        }

//Invoices Table save [Works] (from Invoices.cs)
 private void saveInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iRecord.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateField.Text);
            iRecord.InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(this.invoiceNumField.Text);
            iRecord.Subtotal = (float) Convert.ToDouble(this.subtotalField.Text);
            iRecord.Tax1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(this.hstField.Text);
            iRecord.Total = (float)Convert.ToDouble(this.totalField.Text);
            iRecord.BillTo = this.billToField.Text;
            invoicesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            if (newRecord)
            {
                dSet.Invoices.Rows.Add(iRecord);
                invoicesTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(dSet.Invoices);
            }
            else
            {
                string connString = Properties.Settings.Default.PosDatabaseConnectionString;
                string queryString = "UPDATE dbo.Invoices set ";
                queryString += "Date='" + iRecord.Date+"'";
                queryString += ", Subtotal=" + iRecord.Subtotal;
                queryString += ", Tax1=" + iRecord.Tax1.ToString("N2");
                queryString += ", Total=" + iRecord.Total;
                queryString += " WHERE InvoiceNo=" + iRecord.InvoiceNo;
                using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn);
                    dbConn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dbConn.Close();
                }
            }
            dSet.Invoices.AcceptChanges();
        }

//Invoice Items save [works until restart] (also from Invoices.cs)
  private void addLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                DataRow iRow = dSet.Tables["InvoiceItems"].NewRow();
                iRow["Cost"] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(this.costField.Text);
                iRow["Description"] = this.descriptionField.Text;
                iRow["InvoiceNo"] = Convert.ToInt32(this.invoiceNumField.Text);
                iRow["JobId"] = Convert.ToInt32(this.jobIdField.Text);
                iRow["Qty"] = Convert.ToInt32(this.quantityField.Text);
                iRow["SalesPerson"] = Convert.ToInt32(this.salesPersonField.Text);
                iRow["SKU"] = Convert.ToInt32(this.skuField.Text);

                dSet.Tables["InvoiceItems"].Rows.Add(iRow);
                invoiceItemsTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(dSet,"InvoiceItems");
                PosDatabaseDataSet.InvoiceItemsDataTable dTable = (PosDatabaseDataSet.InvoiceItemsDataTable)dSet.InvoiceItems.Copy();
                DataRow[] d = dTable.Select("InvoiceNo=" + invNo.ToString());
                invoiceItemsView.DataSource = d;

        }
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

UPDATE: October 17, 2011. I am still unable to get this working is there any more ideas out there?

Comment: I wont vote to close yet.  The problem is with your SQL writes and/or data-adapters and dataset code.  Could you please remove anything from your code that isn't SQL, data set or binding source oriented and we can try to help.

Comment: Provided that your InvoiceItemsTableAdapter isn't broken, there is no reason why this shouldn't be updating your code.

Comment: I have looked through all my code and verified the code above gets called and that that is the only code that is being called. It still doesn't stay saved in the database though

Comment: It might be worth note that the add item code is called 0+ times (in most cases 1 for testing sake) and the save invoice is called shortly after

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to verify if after the call to the UpdateAdapter your SQL database is updated.  If it is, something else is deleting the row, otherwise the problem is the table adapter.

Comment: I have responded to that as well

Answer (score 0):

you must execute your Sql Command in order to persis the changes you made.

```
using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  dbConn.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  dbConn.Close();
}
```

The ExecuteReader method is intended (as the name says) to read the data from a SQL table. You need to use a different method as you can see above.

Comment: its interesting, because I think the reader would work, but return zero results.  I agree though that ExecuteNonQuery is the better API to use, not least the fact that it will return the number of rows affected.

Comment: I have updated my code to use this call as well where applicable, thanks!

Comment: It didnt fix my problem though :(

Answer (score 0):

We need some more info first, you haven't shown the case where your code fails.

Common mistakes on this kind of code is calling `DataSet.AcceptChanges()` before actually committing the changes to the database.

Second is a conflict between databound data through the binding source vs edits to the dataset directly.

Lets see the appropriate code and we can try and help.

Set a breakpoint after teh call to invoiceItemsTableAdapter and check the InvoiceItems table for the row you have added.  Release the breakpoint and then close your app.  Check the database again.  I would say that another table may be forcibly overwriting the invoice item table.

Comment: Ive inserted the breakpoint, checking the invoiceitems table confirms that the record has been added. I released the breakpoint and quit the app (at this point i did a stop operation and a normal quit in seperate runs), restarted the program having changed nothing and in both cases the table was empty on start up

Comment: As a side note I searched the entire solution for references to "InvoiceItems" and the above, a single report (which is and isnt being run in seperate instances seemingly having no baring), the design properties of the form which entry occurs (disabling the use of the view so that they must use my text boxes), and the data sets class declaration it is not mentioned

Comment: as for the table adapter I have no idea how it could be broken since the only values I can see for it that can be modified are exactly the same as the invoices one except its for a different table

Comment: So when you said the "record has been added" then you have run a SQL query to confirm its there.  When you restart your app its gone.  something must be executing a delete on teh table, OR you have a transaction surrounding the entire operation that isn't being committed.

Comment: Well once the app is shut down I cant query any of the tables in Visual Studio 2010 it simply says data isn't there even for tables that it remembers the data for. When I confirm its there I'm checking that the count for the table has increased. I'm not using any transactions.

Comment: Hang on.  How are you "checking" the database.  Check your connection string and/or connection string building code.  SQL Server is stand alone.  You can open the SQL Management studio and execute "Select Count(*) from MyTable".  If that isn't incrementing then your code isn't connected to that database.  I think you need to write a much simpler test code to see if you can make a row appear in a table.

Comment: I cant connect to it in visual studio. Ive been checking it with the visual studio debugger. When I check it in visual studio the tables are empty always. Even though I will run the program save things, the invoice table appears empty in the visual studio offline database querier then I run the program again and the table still has info in it, this is also true of the compiled program. The only table that is ACTUALLY empty at any given time is the invoice items table

Comment: The program itself has an interface to view every table